# strange space width on Eclipse4.11, Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: eclipse

Both line 21 and line 25 have same number of space, but they have different indentation:

[image]

When comment star is followd by alpabet cods, it change to a asterisk:

[image]

How to fix?

This is font settig, it is default, font name is **Monospace**.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resoved this problem by changing "Java Editor Text Font" on Eclipse preferences.